# SSRS 2016 - How to display a chart, based on a condition, in the same page location

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I am creating a SSRS Report (PPT export) with multiple charts and fixed number of pages. Each page contains multiple charts. I want to display different charts in the same page location based on a condition.

Now I know that ,we can Hide/Show a chart by specifying an expression for visibility attribute, but this will only Hide/Show the single type of chart in a preassigned location.

Just to reiterate

```
If Condition1=True    
     Display Chart1 at location (0,0) 
Else    
     Display Chart2 at location (0,0)
```

**Note:** Chart1 and Chart2 are generated from different datasets

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple to accomplish.

Create both charts and place them on top of each other in the report designer. Set up your visibility settings to only show one based on your criteria and as only one gets rendered, they will not interfere with each other or the rest of the report layout.

Answer (score 0):

I Think position property for Chart is not available, so we can not manage chart position directly with any position parameter. but there is work around. create your all charts (multiple charts)  in your report design, position them as you want and change their visible property as per your conditions.
e.g. if Chart1 to be displayed at position1 and position 2 based on condition, there will be 2 charts in your report RDL one at position1 and another at position2. manage each charts visible property as per condition, you should achieve what you need.

this is tried by me earlier.